# Access to Amazon EC2 Windows instance via Remote Desktop

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, remote-desktop, amazon-ami

I'm new to AWS EC2 and I'm trying to access to a windows instance (it's an image created from another instance),

But when I click on **Get password** in RDP section, i got this message:

[image: Error message]

The instance was running since yesterday so why I still have this message? is this something related to missing configuration?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check the console output for the instance to see whether the AMI that you used to launch it was created with password generation disabled. If password generation is disabled, the console output contains the following:

```
Ec2SetPassword: Disabled
```

If password generation is disabled and you don't remember the password for the original instance, you can reset the password for this instance. For more information, see .[Reset a lost or expired Windows administrator password](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ResettingAdminPassword.html)

Comment: Hi Asri, thanks for your comment, where can I check the console output ? if it's under action -> Monitor & troubleshoot -> get system log, so the console is empty and it doesn't contains "Ec2SetPassword: Disabled"